# Section title not returent properly by fetchRequestController

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

```
    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.frc sections] count];
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.frc sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.frc sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    return [sectionInfo name];
}
```

I should have one section, with the title before it ... In stead this code puts the title after it ... like the first section has no title but the second one has the title of the first but no content (there shouldn't be a second section)

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

it is for a footer, try to use this one instead:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```